# Can't install Typescript on mac

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, typescript, npm

I've tried to follow the [steps mentioned in the TypeScriptLang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links) but I am not able to download typescript.

Here's what I've tried:

```
mkotsollariss-MacBook-Pro:/ mkotsollaris$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
mkotsollariss-MacBook-Pro:/ mkotsollaris$ which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
mkotsollariss-MacBook-Pro:/ mkotsollaris$ npm install -g typescript
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/lib
└── typescript@2.1.5 

npm ERR! Darwin 16.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "typescript"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Darwin 16.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "typescript"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.3182471724
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.3182471724'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.3182471724'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'npm-debug.log.3182471724' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
mkotsollariss-MacBook-Pro:/ mkotsollaris$
```

When I sudo the typescript install:

```
mkotsollariss-MacBook-Pro:/ mkotsollaris$ sudo npm install -g typescript
Password:
/Applications/IBM/SoftwareDeliveryPlatform_1/cordova_cli/bin/tsc -> /Applications/IBM/SoftwareDeliveryPlatform_1/cordova_cli/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
/Applications/IBM/SoftwareDeliveryPlatform_1/cordova_cli/bin/tsserver -> /Applications/IBM/SoftwareDeliveryPlatform_1/cordova_cli/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver
/Applications/IBM/SoftwareDeliveryPlatform_1/cordova_cli/lib
└── typescript@2.1.5 

mkotsollariss-MacBook-Pro:/ mkotsollaris$ which tsc
mkotsollariss-MacBook-Pro:/ mkotsollaris$ tsc
-bash: tsc: command not found
mkotsollariss-MacBook-Pro:/ mkotsollaris$
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the path it's installing it into; chances are it's not in your $PATH. Have a look at the NPM docs about installing global modules and how you can work around macOS's permissions structure.

Comment: It's much more helpful to paste the relevant console output into a code block than to use screenshots.

Comment: Updated. I believe I will have to update my usr permissions.

Comment: @MenelaosKotsollaris: no, you have to update your `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are having troubles with your user permissions. Have a look at this link:

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: This answer actually solved my case of failing non-global/local install due to global permission issues.